# Unable install Pytorch from source for older GPU card

Tags: python, pytorch

Good day,

I am going fast.ai courses for deep learning. I want to set up locally fastai environment. However, when I try running the first part of the tutorial, I receive an error message stating:

Found GPU0 GeForce GTX 860M which is of cuda capability 5.0.
PyTorch no longer supports this GPU because it is too old.

I found that the problem is related to Pytorch version, which does not support older GPU cards. I found a solution to install older Pytorch from source: http://forums.fast.ai/t/pytorch-not-working-with-an-old-nvidia-card/14632/7

However, when I clone pytorch git and try to install with install.py, I receive a message error.

python setup.py install
running install
running build_deps
error: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

I have navigated to the correct folder “~\Fast_AI\Github material\fastai\pytorch”, when I list the files I can see setup.py, but it does not allow to run.

Could anyone help solve this problem? I could use CPU, however, it works very slowly when working with deep learning, therefore I would prefer to use GPU.

Comment: Received an answer from another forum. I downloaded windows installation file and used conda to install not from local source, but from local file:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B-X0-FlSGfCYdTNldW02UGl4MXM